# How to get a percentage out of a number in an if statement in php?

Tags: php

As the title implies, I need to basically calculate a percentage of a number.

The theory is this: 
If the number is below/lesser than 999 then calculate 5%
If the number is above/greater than 999 then calculate 10%

So far this is what I have tried:

```
<?php
//@$x = $_POST["ost"];
//@$y = $_POST["percent"];

if (count($_POST["ost"]) < 999) 
{ 
@$sum=($percent / 100) * $ost;
}

  ?>
<body>
        <form method="post">

            <p><u>Ostu Hind</u></p>

            <!-- user input -->
            <input type="number" name="ost" min="1" value="500">

            <!-- percent-->
            <input type="number" name="percent" value="5" readonly="yes" disabled="yes">

            <!-- answer -->
            <input type="text" name="answer" readonly="yes" value="<?php echo @$sum ?>">

            <!-- Submit -->
            <input type="Submit" name="Submit">
        </form>
</body
```

Theoretically, the user inputs a number into `OST` and then it goes through the `IF` check, calculates the sum and echoes into `ANSWER`.

But right now it doesn't understand what I mean by "OST".

I need to understand how I can essentially get the IF to count OST's input and then do the calculation there. But i have no idea how to do this nor don't my researches seem to help.

Comment: This isn't really the place for code review but what is the error you are seeing? I can see right off the bat the `$ost` isn't set to anything. So you would need to `$ost = $_POST['ost'];` to remedy that.

Comment: is this an array $_POST["ost"]? why are you using count here? plus to calculate %age you need to multiply result by 100 not the number you are getting.

Comment: *"But right now it doesn't understand what I mean by "OST"."* -- ?!

Comment: Hint: `<input type="number" name="ost" min="1" value="500">`  That said, `$percent` is never defined, you're suppressing your assignment for some really odd reason, and `$sum` will only exist if the form  has been submitted.

Comment: put you php code in a if block , if(isset($_POST['submit']){//your code} .. As you need to perform calculations after form is submitted. (not when page gets open)

Comment: Indeed using the count function was false and I saw the error in my calculation a more logical calc would be (percent*ost)/100. Php didn't understand what OST meant as it wasn't set to anything.
And since my calculations essentially only exist when the form has been submitted I need to use the isset function, okay a bit to wrap my head around, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `count()` .. That is used to count the number objects in an array or object. You also don't need an input for `$Percent` as you are determining that by the value of your ost input.

Try the following

```
$sum = 0;
if (isset($_POST["ost"])) {
    $Percent = .1;
    if ($_POST["ost"] < 999) { 
        $Percent = .05;
    } 

    $sum = $Percent * $_POST["ost"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use `count($var)` in your example. Please, try the code below:

```
  $sum = 0;
  if (isset($_POST["ost"])) {
     $ost = intval($_POST["ost"]);
     $percentage = ($ost < 999) ? 0.05 : 0.1;
     $sum = $percentage * $ost;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this an array $_POST["ost"]? why are you using count here? plus to calculate %age you need to multiply the percentage by the number not like the way you are doing right now.

You are seeking something like this:

```
if ($_POST["ost"] < 999) 
{ 
    @$sum = $_POST["ost"] * 0.05;
}
else
{
    @$sum = $_POST["ost"] * 0.1;
}
```

Also by OST you mean the value you are getting from this input field:

```
    <input type="number" name="ost" min="1" value="500">
```

Answer (score 1):

Since $_POST['ost'] is not an array, you don't need the count() function. 
Your variables ($ost and $percentage) are not set to anything and you need to make sure that the script only runs if someone is submitting your form.

```
$ost = $_POST['ost'];
if(isset($ost){    
  if($ost < 999){
    $percentage = 0.05;
  } else {
    $percentage = 0.10;
  }
 $sum = $ost * $percentage;
}
```